# Running batch files sequentially in win 7 task scheduler

Tags: windows, task, scheduler

I have 2 batch files as "actions" in a single task.  The first one does a scan for viruses using microsoft security essentials.  The second one puts the computer to sleep.  The problem is that when the task is run, it seems like both batch files run simultaneously, that is, I can see the start of the virus scan, but then the computer goes to sleep almost immediately, so the scan really never has a chance to start.  I understood that batch files would run in sequential order in the task scheduler.  Am I wrong?  How do I make the sleep batch file wait until the scan batch file has completed?  Here are the 2 simple batch files...

**Batch file one**

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Essentials\MpCmdRun.exe" -scan -scantype 1

**Batch file two**

powercfg -h off

rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0

powercfg -h on

Answer (score 33):

It's possible using Windows Scheduled Tasks for Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista.

From Microsoft [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722129.aspx):

> A task action is the work that is performed when the task is run. A task can have a single action or a maximum of 32 actions. Each action contains settings that determine how the action is performed. A task's actions are displayed on the Actions tab of the Task Properties or Create Task dialog box. **When multiple actions are specified, they are executed in sequential order** starting with the action at the top of the list in the Actions tab...

Comment: Thanks for highlighting it is in sequential order

Comment: I'm confused. OP said it's not working sequential for him but this answer is saying it should be sequential... So what is the solution exactly?

Comment: @Sal I'm guessing that in the OP's case, the scan was starting in the background and then immediately returning, allowing the second command to run.

Comment: And for anybody stumbling on this answer, sequential actions in Task Scheduler are *blocking* (i.e. Task A runs *and completes* before Task B starts), as opposed to simply starting in sequential order (where Task B could start while Task A was still running).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to fix this is to have the first batch file call the second batch file.  Since the commands in batch files are processed sequentially that would fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the work around.  I was really hoping to use the windows task scheduler for this and a number of other batch files that must run sequentially, not concurrently.

Comment: @Jim You can't get the task scheduler to do this, it's just the nature of the beast.  @LeoB's answer is not a workaround it is the solution.  Perhaps what you want is another batch file that simply calls each of your worker batch files in order.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes you can.

Comment: @ruionwriting at the time that answer was posted it was not possible. Now it is.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is for the action to contain `START /W C:\MyScript.bat`  The **/W** is a parameter for the start command to wait for completion before returning control.