# Task Scheduler - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have 5 files that I would like to schedule to run monthly in windows 7 task scheduler. Problem is I want them to run in succession of one another.

Example:

File1 (this runs first)
File2 (this runs after file 1 is done running)
File3 (this runs after file 2 is done running)

and so on...

How do I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running batch files sequentially in win 7 task scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391768/running-batch-files-sequentially-in-win-7-task-scheduler)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Windows Help (applies to Vista or later):

A task action is the work that is performed when the task is run. A task can have a single action or a maximum of 32 actions. Each action contains settings that determine how the action is performed. A task's actions are displayed on the **Actions** tab of the **Task Properties** or **Create Task** dialog box. When multiple actions are specified, they are executed in sequential order starting with the action at the top of the list in the **Actions** tab and ending with the action at the bottom of the list. You can change the order in which the actions are executed by selecting an action and clicking on the up or down arrow button to move the action in the list.

Comment: @Neil How do the make the execution of the actions asynchronous?

Comment: @BenHooper They are asynchronous, in the sense that they run in sequence. If you want all tasks to run at the same time (in parallel) I guess the easiest would be to create multiple tasks to run at the same time.

Comment: @aland Hmm. I was afraid you'd say that. Okay, if you want to post that as an answer to my question regarding this I'll accept it if no better solutions are suggested soon: http://superuser.com/questions/497784/asynchronous-task-scheduler-actions. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, @aland doesn't know the definition of asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file containing all of your commands one after the other and then schedule the batch file to run.